# About Sappho's epigram for the little girl Aithopia: first line (manuscript tradition and experts' take), and authorship

Tags: poetry, greek-language, sappho

### **Background and research:**

As I am planning to post this poem on [my blog](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/) relatively soon, I was doing some research on the first line. From what I had written previously, I seem to have found two different versions:

> Παῖδες, ἄφωνος ἔοισα τόδ' ἐννέπω, αἴ τις ἔραται

or:

> Καίπερ ἄφωνος ἔοισα ποτεννέπω, αἴ τις ἔραται

I opted for the first one for my translations, because `καίπερ` only stresses the concessive (is that the word?) nature of the participle, and I preferred to have a vocative there like `παῖδες`, and also because instead of a seemingly useless prefix I preferred an object for the verb `ἐννέπω`. Tonight I was trying to get more info on the sources. I looked into [bibliotheca Augustana](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/graeca/Chronologia/S_ante06/Sappho/sap_intr.html), and the `ἐπιγράμματα` link does not exist. I looked at Edmonds (who proposes another version, `παῖς ἔτ'`, which I prefer to the one I opted for back in the days, and has `τόρ'` instead of the object, an adjective referred to the speaker meaning "clear, distinct", perhaps I will adopt this reading), and he says `Anth. Pal. 6 269`. Sadly, I found no scans of that. I looked at [Campbell](https://www.scribd.com/doc/34720745/Sappho-and-Alcaeus-Loeb) hoping for a more detailed critical note, and the poem isn't there! [Wharton](https://ia802704.us.archive.org/22/items/sapphomemoirtex00bunngoog/sapphomemoirtex00bunngoog.pdf) agrees with me, [The Complete Poems of Sappho](http://inamidst.com/stuff/sappho/) follows Cox (or so he says), and ends up agreeing with my choice -- almost, he has `τότ'` instead of `τόδ'`, perhaps a typo, as "then" doesn't seem to fit in there. I'm starting to wonder where I got the other choices. Well, the `καίπερ` might have been off the weird safopoemas.doc (pdf version [here](http://ftp.utalca.cl/intercambio/plataforma/lgc/Dani/Libros/Para%20imprimir/Poemas_completos_Safo.pdf)), for which cfr. [my post on the completion of Sappho 94](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/who-put-forward-this-completion-to-sappho-94-and-what-is-it-actually-supposed-t). But the other thing? Even [the Greek Wikisource](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%8E%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B9_%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9_%CE%95%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%B1) completely agrees with me on this! Googling `Σαϋναϊάδα` yields [this](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/sappho-fragments/1982/pb_LCL142.205.xml) with `ποτεννέπω`. I don't remember this source, but perhaps that was it.

---

### **Question:**

###### **I am wondering what the experts think about this line, what the likeliest "correct" reading is, what the sources for this poem have to say, and why Campbell doesn't include it.**

Is it perhaps of disputed authorship, along with the other two epigrams in elegiac couplets?

---

### Addenda: **Reference to Greek Wikisource with texts of epigrams**

Two of these (the present one is Απόσπασμα 118, the other one 119) can be found [here](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%8E%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B9_%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9_%CE%95%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%B8%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%B1). The third one, to the fisher Pelagon (`τῷ γρίπει Πελάγωνι πάτηρ ἐπέθηκε Μένισκος / Κύρτον καὶ κώπαν, μνᾶμα κακοζοΐας`), has strangely been removed even from there. Somebody [here](https://el.wikisource.org/wiki/%CE%95%CF%80%CE%B9%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1_%CE%A3%CE%B1%CF%80%CF%86%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%82) probably doesn't have a clear idea what an epigram is :). Anyway here is someone following Edmonds on the poem of the question and including all 3 epigrams.

**Bergk**

[Bergk p. 636](https://ia600207.us.archive.org/18/items/poetaelyricigrae00berguoft/poetaelyricigrae00berguoft.pdf) ha all epigrams, his line 1 reads:

> Παῖδες, ἄφωνος ἐοῖσα τότ' ἐννέπω, αἴ τις ἔρηται

and he has this critical note:

> [image: Bergk's critical note for the epigram]

**Acknowledging a mistake**

Whoopsies! I missed them in Campbell because they were in smaller font. p. 113. Et voilà: good morning `ποτεννέπω`, though Campbell agrees on the vocative. Here is a screenshot of all the epigrams in Campbell:

> [image: The three epigrams in Campbell's Sappho edition]

Comment: Hey. I fixed a typo in your post, and also removed the default alt text from your picture; the alt text is there to make it easier for people and machines that can't see images, and the default text is worse than nothing. If you could [edit] your question to include a useful alt text, that would be great. (I'd offer to help, but this post is all Greek to me :P) See https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/489/481 and some of the links therein for more information.

Comment: @Shokhet done that.

Comment: Perhaps someone on the [latin.se] site can answer this excellent question, as it seems it has languished without an answer for many years here. Latin Stack Exchange [does accept questions about ancient Greek](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/policy-on-greek-questions)

Comment: @verbose I [cross-posted this one week after posting here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4605/about-sapphos-epigram-for-the-little-girl-aithopia-first-line-manuscript-trad) :).